# Jquery getting the clicked row contents

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery 1.10.1.

I have a table that is initially not present on the page. The table is rendered with an ajax call when the user selects something from a drop down box. This is query. The table is rendered at that point. The loop is working, the table is rendering.

```
var output = '<table id="slots" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">';
output += '<thead>';
output += '<tr>';
output += '<th>Select</th>';
output += '<th>Date</th>';
output += '<th>Time</th>';
output += '<th>Room</th>';
output += '</tr>';
output += '</thead>';
output += '<tbody>';
$(result).find("RESULTS").each(function() {
//loop through each row
var room = $(this).find('room').text();
var id = $(this).find('id').text();
var date = $(this).find('aDate').text();
var time = $(this).find('aTime').text();
output += "<tr><td class=id>" + id + "</td><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + time  + "</td><td>" + room + "</td></tr>";
}); // of each function
```

So far so good...

Now the clicking piece. I'm doing baby steps...and this doesn't even work... it is inside the master $("document").ready(function(). I was wondering if that's part of the issue as #slots is not in the DOM when it's first rendered. I am not getting an alert here. It doesn't seem to find or have bound the "click" function. I found this snippet from another post.

```
$('#slots').find('tr').click( function(){
    alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

Ultimately I want to grab the value of the id, date, time and room from the selected row and do something more with that. Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to this.

Comment: In that case you ca try using event delegation `$(document).on('click', '#slots tr', function(){
    alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});)` or bind the event after doing your operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.on()`'s delegated event syntax](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) instead of `click()`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#slots tr', function(){
    alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) );
});
```

Comment: wow, that was easy... thank you. Makes sense. My follow up question is therefore best method for getting the value of the 1st , 2nd, 3rd, 4th td text value? (this is not initialized as a datatable - just plain old <table> html right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate the event since it's not created in the initial DOM load

```
$(document).on('click', '#slots tr', function(){ 
    alert('You clicked row '+ ($(this).index()+1) ); 
});
```

Comment: spot on with the other post - sorry I can't mark both as checked.